# Magento 2.0 rawQuery, How to escape strings

Tags: magento2, database, sql, magento-2.0

I have this code, which was converted from a plugin created in Opencart.
Is there a function in Magento 2.0 to escape strings as the function **mysql_escape_string** can't be used in Magento 2.0?

```
$oc_item_synchro_tbl = $this->getRs()->getTableName('oc_item_synchro');
$oc_other_config = mysql_escape_string($serialized);
$id = 255;
$this->getConnection()->rawQuery("UPDATE $oc_item_synchro_tbl SET oc_other_config = '$oc_other_config' WHERE oc_product_id = '$id'");
```

UPDATED code:

```
public function addProduct($data)
{

    $oc_item_synchro = $this->getRs()->getTableName('oc_item_synchro');
    $id = (int)$data['oc_product_id'];
    $now = strtotime("Y-m-d h:ia");
    $conn = $this->getConnection('core_write');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $oc_item_synchro SET ";
    $sql .= "oc_product_id = :OC_PRODUCT_ID, ";
    $sql .= "oc_item_category_id = :OC_ITEM_CATEGORY_ID, ";
    $sql .= "oc_item_duration = :OC_ITEM_DURATION, ";
    $sql .= "item_delivery_time = :ITEM_DELIVERY_TIME, ";
    $sql .= "is_posted = :IS_POSTED, ";
    $sql .= "oc_synchro_time = :NOW";
    $binds = array(
        'OC_PRODUCT_ID' => $id,
        'OC_ITEM_CATEGORY_ID' => (int)$data['oc_item_category_id'],
        'OC_ITEM_DURATION' => $data['oc_item_duration'],
        'ITEM_DELIVERY_TIME' => $data['item_delivery_time'],
        'IS_POSTED' => (!empty($data['is_posted']) ? 1 : 0),
        'NOW' => $now
    );
    $conn->query($sql, $binds);

    $sql2 = "UPDATE $oc_item_synchro SET ";
    $sql2 .= "oc_other_config = :OC_OTHER_CONFIG ";
    $sql2 .= "WHERE oc_product_id = :OC_PRODUCT_ID";
    $binds2 = array(
        'OC_OTHER_CONFIG' => serialize($data['oc_other_config']),
        'OC_PRODUCT_ID' => $id
    );
    $conn->query($sql2, $binds2);
}
```

Comment: Ok, I tried using binding method like below, but eventhough I don't see error, the data is not saved.  Any of you can point out what the issue is?

Answer (score 2):

Since Magento2 uses PDO then you can use PDO::quote();

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$sql = "update mymodule_shipping set method='$_REQUEST[method]' where mymodule_shipping_id=$_REQUEST[m_shipping_id]";
$sql = $connection->quote($sql);
$connection->query($sql);
```

Connection inherits methods from PDO, or at least seems to, I test it worked.

You can use DI instead of Object Manager but that would take me about 10x as long to explain because it's badly designed.

PDO documentation discourages using PDO::quote() stating things that aren't factually true about prepared statements like that query caching can't work without prepared statements which is objectively false.  Anyway, here's the code you asked for hope it helps.

I'm not sure if it's as safe as mysql_real_escape_string because I'm not sure if it retrieves the character set and escapes it from the connection or not but it is PDO's "answer" to escaping strings for queries.

Comment: You should Quote individual request parameters, not the whole query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use connection quote

```
$this->connection->quote($value)
```

For example in original question

```
$this->getConnection()->rawQuery("UPDATE $oc_item_synchro_tbl 
SET oc_other_config = '$oc_other_config' WHERE oc_product_id = '$id'");
```

This now become

```
$query = sprintf(
    "UPDATE %s SET oc_other_config = %s WHERE oc_product_id = %s",
     $oc_item_synchro_tbl,
     $this->getConnection()->quote($oc_other_config),
     $this->getConnection()->quote($id)
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Magento 2 uses PDO for MySQL by default, so you're safe if you are using prepared statements - which you already do, with named bindings. No need for `mysql_escape_string` (which is deprecated, btw, just like `mysql_real_escape_string`).

Comment: This is wierd I put comment here yesterday that this was working already.  Anyways, the Updated code was indeed working but somehow, the **exit;** code I put before the closing tag of the execute method caused the issue.  Removing the **exit;** and **clearing the cache** seem to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Looking for the same thing, answer above does not help.

Comment: @leedch - well, your comment doesn't help either. Maybe you're doing it wrong. It worked for OP.

Comment: You're right, I should explain myself better.

There are always situations where you know what SQL statement you want to execute and very often these situations include dynamic parameters that need escaping. In these cases it does not help if someone tells you escaping is deprecated because of prepared statements. If you don't want to use/learn prepared statements, but just want to escape the dangerous variables, then you want an alternate function to do that and not a new design pattern to learn.

Comment: I understand, but I really do think there is _no way_ to properly protect yourself from SQL injection by escaping strings. The _only_ way I know is to send *two* separate data to the SQL server: the query, _then_ its dynamic values you want escaped (aka prepared statements). Every time you send _all the data in one go_ you risk an injection. In this regard, you _must_ learn prepared statements. I don't want to remind people what year this is. That would be... unfriendly.

Comment: Some people don't like prepared statements, they aren't a new thing, they've been around for ages and always been an unnecessary pita.  Answers are supposed to answer questions not insert opinion pieces on prepared statements.  You don't have to send all the text in one go with escaping either.